# How to only load content when a colorbox popup is activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, colorbox

I've got 15 products on a web page and each product has a link which opens a colobox div with 9 thumbnails (jpg / 360x270 pixels). It means 135 pictures are loading and sometimes it can takes near 10 seconds to load the page!

I would like to avoid that slowness. So how to only load content of one product (9 thumbnails) when a colorbox popup is activated?

Comment: what is colobox? Do you mean this? http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: Definitely investigate AJAX loading (it was designed for this); also what does your User analysis tell you?  Are all 15 products on the page equally likely to be clicked?  Really?

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to request the data from the server? A couple of ways this can be achieved with Colorbox, it is a smart tool.

- [How to only load content when a colorbox popup is activated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711500/how-to-only-load-content-when-a-colobox-popup-is-activated)
- Or load a partial view inside your colorbox, would probably work well, try this link: http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/20/mvc-render-partial-modal-pop-up-via-jquery-and-colorbox-part-2/